# Using #DEBUG macros in spark

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I have some scripts which need to be included only in the release version. Stuff like google analytics, quantserve etc.

The typical way in asp.net mvc world is to wrap a

```
#if DEBUG
#endif
```

How do I do it the [sparkish way](http://dev.dejardin.org/documentation/expressions). Like

```
<script if='x==5' type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify a custom Base Page for the Views.

```
    public abstract class BaseSparkView<TModel> : Spark.Web.Mvc.SparkView<TModel> where TModel : class
    {

        public bool IsDebug
        {
            get
            {
#if DEBUG
                return true;
#else
                return false;
#endif
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in your web.config create the spark section

```
<spark>
    <pages pageBaseType="BaseSparkView" />
</spark>
```

And finally in your page you could do this...

```
<script if='IsDebug' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Or <script if='!IsDebug' type="text/javascript"></script> as the case may be in you original question :-P

Answer (score 2):

```
##if DEBUG
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
##endif
```

Should work.

Comment: I think he wanted the inline condition expression style but this approach is certainly much more straightforward

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion, what if you do this:

```
<% #if DEBUG %>
<script if='x==5' type="text/javascript">
<$ #endif %>
```

Note the space between % and #.
Don't know if this will work or not, has to be worth a try!

Comment: default approach.Not sparkish